# Magento 2 import stuck 503 (Service Unavailable)

Tags: magento2, import

I am trying to import some files with CSV on magento 2, when i click check data, it nevers loads. when i click f12 i get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
>
> magento/admin_[admin]/admin/import/validate/key/[key]/?form_key=[form
>   key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should export the CSV format from magento 2 than you can changes in CSV and again upload this CSV in magento 2. I hope you understand.

Comment: Carefull, export configurable products with more than 1 variation failed!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an improperly formatted CSV file. When saving out of excel ensure you are saving as "Windows Comma Separated (.csv)". This is especially important if working on a mac.

Also, if working on a mac ensure that the .csv file type is assigned. It will still open in mac excel without it but will not be recognized on the Magento import function.